# how to copy selected data from stringgrid

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8, stringgrid

i couldn't find the way to copy selected cell data from a stringgrid, i want the selected data string to be copied to Edit box if possible.. many thanks in advance.
im using delphi xe8, firemonkey.

what i tried so far..

```
Private
A : Array of TValue;
procedure TForm1.Grid1GetValue(Sender: TObject; const Col, Row: Integer; var        Value: TValue);
 begin
// Gets the value from a cell in the first column
if Col = 0 then
 Value := A[Row];

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
A[1] := Edit1.Text;
end;
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? Surely all you need to do is read text from the grid, and write text to the edit. Which part of this are you stuck with?

Comment: i couldn't do anything, all codes are related to VCL !, im stuck with the codes and the copy process @David Heffernan

Comment: First of all, do you know how you set the text of an edit control? Did you look in the documentation?

Comment: well, im still a beginner, what documentation?there is nothing at docwiki about stringgrids!@David Heffernan

Comment: There certainly is documentation for these controls. Search for docwiki fmx TStringGrid delphi.

Comment: If you want to use Firemonkey, you should seriously consider upgrading to one of the later versions, such as XE8. XE2 was the very first version introducing Firemonkey, and it was extremely primitive back then.

Comment: i mentioned that i use XE8 @Jerry Dodge

Comment: @markkk Oh, I saw the `delphi-xe2` tag, which appears to be corrected now.

Comment: I've tried something, can u insight me plz now.@David Heffernan

Comment: Your code makes no sense to me. We don't know what `A` is. I recommend that you read the documentation. Slow down, step back, and try harder.

Comment: A:Array of TValue, i really dont have time to study this component, any help will be appreciated. @David Heffernan

Comment: You don't have time? In that case neither do I.

Comment: If you can't find the time to present enough code for us to debug for you, then why should we take the time to guess what *might* be wrong in the rest of the code which we cannot see? Your code is incomplete and uncompilable.

Comment: there is nothing special, just a stringgrid with 2 columns filled with string !!. i want to select a cell from col2 and copy its data to Edit box, @Jerry Dodge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//i spent hours just to figure it out,waste of TIME;//

Procedure Formx.StringGrid1SellectCell(Sender: TObject; const ACol,Arow: integer;   var CanSellect: Boolean);
Var
Val: string;
begin
Val := StringGrid1.Cells[ACol, ARow];
Edit1.Text:= Val;
```

Comment: That code does not compile. If you'd only read the documentation.... That said, in your defence, they official code example is bizarre. I guess that put you on the wrong track.

Comment: it works for me like charm,, u could've wrote the code under 20 sec insted of wasting 8h of my time, anyway,thanks@David Heffernan

Comment: The code does not compile. Your sense of entitlement is a sign of weakness. We aren't here to write your code for you. We like to teach. You are not interested in learning.

Comment: easy son, the code dose Compile, I've tested it!!, if u don't want to write a single line of code there is trustworthy ppl ready to do it ! @David Heffernan

Comment: Your code compiles. The code in the answer does not.

Comment: YES it dose. try it @David Heffernan

Comment: The code in the answer does not compile. `Celles`? What you need to learn is how to research for yourself, and also that this site is not a place where people write your code for you. We like to help people that are keen to learn.

Comment: i get it, because of [,] instead of [.]. u kidding me!, don't start to lecturer me plz, im probably way older than u,however. many thanks kid @David Heffernan

Comment: No. There's no member of the class named `Celles`. Where does age come into it? It doesn't matter how old you are.

Comment: So, there is a lesson to be learnt here. Do you want to hear it?

Comment: hahaha, i didnt copy and past it, i WROTE it, that's why,@David Heffernan

Comment: So, would you like to hear the lesson, or not?

Comment: Well, if you don't want to learn, you are in the wrong place.

Comment: kid, its about the circumstances not just about learning. @David Heffernan